# Accessing Active Directory with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, active-directory

I am trying to access Active Directory, which I can successfully do in Visual Studio using basically the same code as below. However, I'm getting an error with this line of code when using Unity: "DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry("xxxxxxx");"

String username = "xxxxx xxxxxxx";

```
        try
        {
            DirectoryEntry myLdapConnection = createDirectoryEntry();

            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(myLdapConnection);
            search.Filter = "(cn=" + username + ")";

            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

            if (result != null)
            {
                print("user found");
            }
            else
            {
                print("user not found");
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {

            print("Exception caught:" + e.ToString());
        }
    }

    static DirectoryEntry createDirectoryEntry()
    {
        DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry("xxxxxxx");
        ldapConnection.Path = "LDAP://OU=xxxxxx,DC=xxxxxx,DC=xxxxx,DC=xxxxx";
        ldapConnection.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;
        return ldapConnection;
    }
```

The error is: "Invalid IL code in System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry:.cctor (): method body is empty."

Any help on the reason for this or a possible solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Greetings, and welcome to SO. Did you try to instantiate with the constructor public DirectoryEntry(
    string path,
    string username,
    string password,
    AuthenticationTypes authenticationType)? give it a try and inform me for the results.

Comment: This didn't work. Issue resolved using Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard.dll.